# Shell Script to replace multiple instances of unix timestamps in a file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a file which has data similar to the following:

```
>       <Element     
>       Stream="12"
>       Target_trans="133106"
>       Trans="48467"
>       fileModTime="1358349304"
>       Type="1"
>       EOL="0"
>       user_id="33" />   <Element     
>       Stream="14"
>       Target_trans="133106"
>       Trans="48467"
>       fileModTime="1358539304"
>       Type="1"
>       EOL="0"
>       user_id="33" />   <Element     
>       Stream="11"
>       Target_trans="133113"
>       Trans="48467"
>       fileModTime="1158539204"
>       Type="1"
>       EOL="0"
>       user_id="33" />   <Element     
>       Stream="11"
>       Target_trans="133106"
>       Trans="48467"
>       fileModTime="1358129304"
>       Type="1"
>       EOL="0"
>       user_id="33" />
```

I need to go through this file, find all instances of fileModTime which is a unix timestamp and replace the value there with a human readable date and timestamp.

I know the command to change the date.  What im not sure how to do is the actual grepping through the file, extracting the epoch timestamp and passing that into my conversion command.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
awk '/fileModTime/{
  split($0, a, "=")
  gsub(/"/, "", a[2])
  sub(/[0-9]+/, strftime("%F %T", a[2]), $0)
}1' input.xml
```

However, in general it's not a good idea to process XML data line-by-line. You might be better off using an actual XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following sed command:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(fileModTime=\)"\(.*\?\)"/\1"'"$(date -d @\2)"'"/' inFile
```

**EDIT:**

Using awk is better:

```
awk -F'"' '{if ($1 ~ /fileModTime=/) {printf("%s", $1); system("date -d @" $2)}
            else print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe 's/fileModTime="\K\d+/ (localtime $&)->cdate /e' file
```

If the `Wed Jan 16 10:15:04 2013` format doesn't work for you, replace `cdate` with `strftime("your format here")`

If you're satisfied this works, add `-i` before `-pe` to edit the file in-place.